# Using RewriteEngine in PHP to read a file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

recently I'm making a php application and I want some changes in my file.
So I use .htaccess and RewriteEngine and when I want to run my application it said 404.
Here is my code that I try and said 404 !!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^access/(\d+)*$ show.php?address=$1&login=0
```

for example this my original address:
**www.ex.com/show.php?address=5411496bc2b6c&login=0** 
And I want to change it to:
**www.ex.com/access/5411496bc2b6c** 
Here is my question Am I doing something wrong in .htaccess ?

Comment: Is `/access/` a real directory? OR do you have other rules?

Comment: @anubhava no it's not real!

Comment: I asked 2 questions actually :)

Comment: @anubhava I don't get that, if you mean other rules in .htaccess no I just have this

Answer (score 1):

In your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^access/(\d+)*$ show.php?address=$1&login=0
```

Should be:

```
RewriteRule ^access/([a-z0-9]+)$ show.php?address=$1&login=0
```

`(\d+)` means digits and as it seems you need digits + lower alpha characters right?

Also `SCRIPT_FILENAME` will match executing script file name, so it will never be directory and you will also rewrite real existing directories, instead use `REQUEST_URI` or `REQUEST_FILENAME`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

**This works for me:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^access/([a-z0-9]+)$ show.php?address=$1&login=0 [L]
```

Comment: Oops, I don't know that (\d+) means digits, yep the code is the uniqid in php I try your code but I still have 404!

Comment: try final one and tell me

Comment: can you access `show.php?address...` directly? Or do you have some more rewrite rules defined? then use [L]

Comment: I've added `L` flag tnx

Comment: Yep it's work for me BUT the css and javascript are not loaded!

Comment: @ale_x can you access your css files directly? maybe they are linked relative in your html (main.css -> gets /access/main.css) use a facing slash

Comment: you have to add slash to your `css` `js` and `img` also to `links` `/public/css/test.css`

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili maybe its good to have the rewrite base defined `RewriteBase /` with this line it should also work in a dynamic vhost.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^access/([^/]+)/?$ show.php?address=$1&login=0 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Yep, It's work for me, BUT the css and javascript are not load!!

Comment: If you want to allow only word characters then use `RewriteRule ^access/(\w+)/?$ show.php?address=$1&login=0 [L,QSA,NC]` instead.

Comment: For css/js issues use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.